# Linux Function to write group entry into /etc/group

Tags: linux, api, function

While going through the code of an application, i came across the `putpwent()` function which writes a `password entry`. Is there a function similar to this which writes a `group entry` into a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`putgrent()` will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`man 3 putgrent`:

putgrent - write a group database entry to a file

Answer (score 1):

Replace the 'pw' with 'gr': http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/putgrent.3.html